# Giving space in a word

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've a table contain 2 fields DATEFROM & DATETO. Now i fetch dis names from table and display the same, but i want to display like DATE FROM & DATE TO...If it is this possible How? We have any functions like 'explode()'? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only used on those fields then you could use

```
str_replace('DATE', 'DATE ', $dateField);
```

But in that situation there is no way to determine where a word starts/ends otherwise.

If the field names were camel case or separated with underscores then it would be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring() to extract content from fields, if you want to name column differently, use as, e.g. `select datefrom as [date from] from mytable`.